# Mapdist: controlling for traffic

Tags: r, google-maps

I am working on a project in which I need to get the shortest distance and time from "pick-up" to "drop-off" coordinates.
In my dataset I have a variable indicating the "trip_distance" and "pickup_date", my task is to calculate how much the  "trip_distance" variable is deviating from the Google estimated distance and calculate the time that each trip will take by controlling for the departure time.

Here is a small sample of my data (which has about 1.5m rows, I am trying to find a way for the <2,500 queries limitation)

```
trip_distance   pickup_datetime     pickup                  dropoff
1     8.1     2011-01-01 23:13:56    40.77419%2C-73.872608    40.78055%2C-73.955042
2     10.6    2011-01-04 17:12:49    40.7737%2C-73.870721    40.757007%2C-73.971953
3     15.9    2011-01-05 18:41:53   40.773761%2C-73.87086    40.707277%2C-74.007301
```

Code:

```
library(ggmap)
rownames(X) <- NULL
res <- mapdist(from= X$pickup, 
           to = X$dropoff, 
           mode = "driving" ,
           output = "simple", messaging = FALSE, sensor = FALSE,
           language = "en-EN", override_limit = FALSE, departure_time= X$pickup_date)
```

The error I get is:

```
 Error in mapdist(from = X$pickup, to = X$dropoff, mode = "driving",      output = "simple",  :  unused argument (departure_time = X$pickup_date)
```

Is there any way to control for the traffic using mapdist?

dput(head(X))

```
structure(list(pickup_datetime = structure(c(1293923636, 1294161169, 
1294252913, 1294259376, 1294419723, 1293903309), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = ""), trip_distance = c(8.1, 10.6, 15.9, 8.9, 
11.5, 9.6), pickup = c("40.77419,-73.872608", "40.7737,-73.870721", 
"40.773761,-73.87086", "40.773776,-73.870908", "40.774161,-73.87302", 
"40.774135,-73.8749"), dropoff = c("40.78055,-73.955042",         "40.757007,-73.971953", 
"40.707277,-74.007301", "40.770568,-73.95468", "40.758284,-73.986621", 
"40.758691,-73.961359")), .Names = c("pickup_datetime",     "trip_distance", 
"pickup", "dropoff"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Could you please provide us with `dput(head(X))`

Comment: I added it to the question, please find it above. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've written the package [**googleway**](https://github.com/SymbolixAU/googleway) to access google maps API where you can specify your api key, and therefore use the functions provided by the API (such as departure time and traffic)

However, for this you'll need to use the development version as I've noticed a small bug in the `traffic_model`. This will be fixed in the next release.

```
devtools::install_github("SymbolixAU/googleway")
library(googleway)

key <- "your_api_key"

## data.frame of origin & destination coordiantes
## you can obviously add in a 'pickup' datetime column too, 
## but remembering that for Google API it must be in the future
df <- data.frame(orig_lat = c(40.77419, 40.7737, 40.773761),
                 orig_lon = c(-73.872608, -73.870721, -73.87086),
                 dest_lat = c(40.78055, 40.757007, 70.707277),
                 dest_lon = c(-73.955042, -73.971953,-74.007301))
```

Now you can get the distance between each set of points on each row the the data.frame using your preferred looping method

For example

```
lst <- apply(df, 1, function(x) { 
  google_distance(origins = list(c(x["orig_lat"], x["orig_lon"])),
                  destinations = list(c(x["dest_lat"], x["dest_lon"])),
                  departure_time = Sys.time() + (24 * 60 * 60),
                  traffic_model = "best_guess",
                  key = key)
  })
```

Then you can access the data from the returned list

```
lst[[1]]$origin_addresses
# [1] "Central Terminal Dr, East Elmhurst, NY 11371, USA"
lst[[1]]$destination_addresses
# [1] "1294-1296 Lexington Ave, New York, NY 10128, USA"
lst[[1]]$rows$elements
# [[1]]
# distance.text distance.value duration.text duration.value duration_in_traffic.text duration_in_traffic.value status
# 1       12.8 km          12805       21 mins           1278                  23 mins                      1355     OK
```

Answer (score 3):

The `mapdist()` function from `ggmap` will not return traffic information as it does not seem to construct a URL with the `&departure_time=` and `key=` parameters (mandatory to retrieve traffic information)

As per mentionned in the Google Maps Distance Matrix API [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/intro#RequestParameters):

> For requests where the travel mode is driving: You can specify the
>   `departure_time` to receive a route and trip duration (response field:
>   `duration_in_traffic`) that take traffic conditions into account. This
>   option is only available if the request contains a valid **API key**, or a
>   valid **Google Maps APIs Premium Plan client ID and signature**.

Also, in your dataset, the `pickup_date` is in the past so you can't use this as the `departure_time` parameter.

> The `departure_time` must be set to the current time or some time in the
>   future. It cannot be in the past.

And requires a numeric format:

> You can specify the time as an integer in seconds since midnight,
>   January 1, 1970 UTC. Alternatively, you can specify a value of `now`,
>   which sets the departure time to the current time (correct to the
>   nearest second).

---

That being said, you could manually construct your own request to the Google Maps Distance Matrix API using the required parameters (note that I modified your initial dataset to provide a `pickup_datetime` occuring in the future)

```
APIKEY = ##Your API key goes here##

url_string <- paste0("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json",
                     "?origins=", df$pickup,
                     "&destinations=", df$dropoff,
                     # convert POSIXct to numeric
                     "&departure_time=", as.numeric(df$pickup_datetime),
                     "&traffic_model=best_guess",
                     "&key=", APIKEY)
```

This will give you a character vector `url_string` containing all the URLs. You could for example retrieve the information for the first entry:

```
connect <- url(url_string[1])  
tree <- jsonlite::fromJSON(paste(readLines(connect), collapse = ""), 
                           simplifyDataFrame = FALSE)
```

And then access the traffic information using:

```
tree$rows[[1]]$elements[[1]]$duration_in_traffic
```

Which gives:

```
$text
[1] "17 mins"

$value
[1] 1016
```

---

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(pickup_datetime = structure(c(1473923636, 1474161169, 
1474252913, 1474259376, 1474419723, 1473903309), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), trip_distance = c(8.1, 10.6, 15.9, 8.9, 11.5, 9.6
), pickup = c("40.77419,-73.872608", "40.7737,-73.870721", "40.773761,-73.87086", 
"40.773776,-73.870908", "40.774161,-73.87302", "40.774135,-73.8749"
), dropoff = c("40.78055,-73.955042", "40.757007,-73.971953", 
"40.707277,-74.007301", "40.770568,-73.95468", "40.758284,-73.986621", 
"40.758691,-73.961359")), class = "data.frame", .Names = c("pickup_datetime", 
"trip_distance", "pickup", "dropoff"), row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Comment: If I'm correct using this code I can only take the output one by one. How could I get a vector or matrix with all the outputs for all the request? Like I get in my code above. Thanks!

Comment: @Estefy You can just loop through the `url_string`